# Error: failed to start validator: TestValidator startup failed: Custom { kind: Other, error: "Discover failed" }

Tags: solana-test-validator, failed, testvalidator

I am using a Macbook with M1 and getting the error

```
stankosy@Stans-MacBook-Pro solana % solana-test-validator --no-bpf-jit
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: TestValidator startup failed: Custom { kind: Other, error: "Discover failed" }
```

when executing `solana-test-validator` or `solana-test-validator --no-bpf-jit`

I have tried with different Solana versions incl. the latest 1.10.32 stable version by unpacking the binary and building from source.

The ledger logs are in the end as following:

```
[2022-08-08T01:29:01.750449000Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: banking_stage-leader_slot_transaction_errors id=0i slot=244i total=0i account_in_use=0i account_loaded_twice=0i account_not_found=0i blockhash_not_found=0i blockhash_too_old=0i call_chain_too_deep=0i already_processed=0i instruction_error=0i insufficient_funds=0i invalid_account_for_fee=0i invalid_account_index=0i invalid_program_for_execution=0i not_allowed_during_cluster_maintenance=0i invalid_writable_account=0i invalid_rent_paying_account=0i
[2022-08-08T01:29:01.750454000Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: banking_stage-leader_slot_packet_counts id=0i slot=244i total_new_valid_packets=0i newly_failed_sigverify_count=0i exceeded_buffer_limit_dropped_packets_count=0i newly_buffered_packets_count=0i retryable_packets_filtered_count=0i transactions_attempted_execution_count=1i committed_transactions_count=1i committed_transactions_with_successful_result_count=1i retryable_errored_transaction_count=0i retryable_packets_count=0i nonretryable_errored_transactions_count=0i executed_transactions_failed_commit_count=0i cost_model_throttled_transactions_count=0i failed_forwarded_packets_count=0i successful_forwarded_packets_count=0i packet_batch_forward_failure_count=0i cleared_from_buffer_after_forward_count=0i forwardable_batches_count=0i end_of_slot_unprocessed_buffer_len=0i
[2022-08-08T01:29:01.752889000Z INFO  solana_core::cluster_slot_state_verifier] check_slot_agrees_with_cluster()
            slot: 244,
            root: 213,
            slot_state_update: DuplicateConfirmed(DuplicateConfirmedState { duplicate_confirmed_hash: EZFHXMDBMv3YqVLoy17ufuEkXPtV46dHuuZwSSLvtQQw, bank_status: Frozen(EZFHXMDBMv3YqVLoy17ufuEkXPtV46dHuuZwSSLvtQQw) })
[2022-08-08T01:29:01.752922000Z INFO  solana_core::heaviest_subtree_fork_choice] marking fork starting at: (244, EZFHXMDBMv3YqVLoy17ufuEkXPtV46dHuuZwSSLvtQQw) valid candidate
[2022-08-08T01:29:01.778127000Z INFO  solana_gossip::gossip_service] discover failed...
    IP Address        |Age(ms)| Node identifier                              | Version |Gossip|TPUvote| TPU  |TPUfwd| TVU  |TVUfwd|Repair|ServeR|ShredVer
    ------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+--------
    none            me|  6510 | 3KDq9gZDodHZSyY8aTddi4UMv9j8DfvkHS3Z9w9MpJJY | 1.10.34 | none | none | none | none | none | none | none | none | 0
    Nodes: 0
    Spies: 1
Error: failed to start validator: TestValidator startup failed: Custom { kind: Other, error: "Discover failed" }
```

Would appreciate any support on how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: After installing different versions via different methods (binary, from source and regular way from solana documentation) I'm getting the impression that the issue is actually not in M1 chip since the error is different than as reported in some articles.
I assume the error might be caused by something else instead, but still figuring out what..

Comment: this log snippet is insufficient to deduce what's going on.  please publish a full log from process start to error occurrence somewhere and add a link to the description

Answer (score 0):

After long trial and errors I managed to resolve the issue: it turned out to be my firewall of the antivirus (ESET) that has been causing it.
Easy way to test it out is: reboot your pc in Safe mode and see if running the local test validator works. If it does, most likely there is a running software that is causing this issue (as it was firewall in my case).